# Callback if tiles are loaded in Google maps on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, google-maps-android-api-2, reverse-geocoding

I have a scenario,
When coordinates provided by user is landing into the Ocean, and when camera zoom happens to level 18f map tiles are not loading,
`googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(it, 18.0F))`
If I zoom out manually then it starts loading tiles gradually.
So, is there any callback which returns if tiles are loaded or not.
OR
Is there any way to find out if the coordinates provided are landing in Ocean, except the reverse Geocoding method.

I have tried Reverse geocoding, but that will include additional costs for the Api call, which I don't want.

Comment: In which ocean?

Comment: Any Ocean around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you can download and save polygones of Oceans boundaries (e.g. from OpenStreetMap: [Water polygons](https://osmdata.openstreetmap.de/data/water-polygons.html)) and test current coordinates with [`containsLocation(double latitude, double longitude, java.util.List<LatLng> polygon, boolean geodesic)`](https://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/PolyUtil.html#containsLocation-double-double-java.util.List-boolean-) method from [Maps SDK for Android Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility):

> public static boolean containsLocation(double latitude,
> double longitude,
> java.util.List polygon,
> boolean geodesic)
>
> Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.
> The polygon is always considered closed, regardless of whether the
> last point equals the first or not. Inside is defined as not
> containing the South Pole -- the South Pole is always outside. The
> polygon is formed of great ci rcle segments if geodesic is true, and of rhumb
> (loxodromic) segments otherwise.